# Matlab remove previous plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I generate a graph inside GUIDE and I want that when I change few parameters and I push the run button that I put in my GUI, the previous plot disappear and the new one based on the new parameters is shown.

Right now I plot like this

```
h1=plot(x1(ii)*1000,y1(ii)*1000,'o','MarkerSize',5,'color',C{ii});
hold on; grid on;
plot(x2(ii)*1000,y2(ii)*1000,'x','MarkerSize',10,'color',C{ii});
drawnow
```

Using `drawnow` when I modify the parameters `x2,y2` the new plot is displayed, but the previous values of `x2,y2`remain. How can I delete the old values and update the graph using the new values?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Matlab 2014b or newer you can use the `line` returned by `plot`.  See [matlab help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html) for more details.

```
h1 = plot(x1(ii)*1000,y1(ii)*1000,'o','MarkerSize',5,'color',C{ii});
hold on; grid on;
h2 = plot(x2(ii)*1000,y2(ii)*1000,'x','MarkerSize',10,'color',C{ii});
drawnow
```

Then when you want to modify the `h2` line you can just reassign the `XData` and `YData`

```
h2.XData = x2(ii)*2000;
h2.YData = y2(ii)*2000;
```

Comment: I generate the two plots inside a for in a function. What are suggesting me need to be added where exactly? In my code `x2,y2`  are result from others parameters. I don't act directly on them. I modify a parameter that is called inside the function that will generate the two plots.